# How to solve ?:Find all complex numbers such that $|1+w^2|=2|w|$

Tags: complex-numbers

I wanted to work on some complex number problems until I came across this problem. Find all complex numbers $w$ such that $|1+w^2|=2|w|$

---

Work: I tried with the trigonometric form but it didn't give me anything.

Then I tried with the algebraic form and I came to the fact that $(a^2+b^2)^2+1=2a^2+6b^2$
From here I wanted to show that only w=1 checks but it didn't work out for me.

I think a good ideea is to solve it geometrical

Comment: Try writing $w=r\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\theta}$

Comment: I tried ,but it didn't work for me

Comment: There are plenty of other solutions. [_Wolfram Alpha_](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%5E2%2B1%3D2x%5E2%2B6y%5E2) shows them if you change the variable names.

Answer (score 3):

You have solved it! I changed the notation to $x$ and $y$, but then $$(x^2+y^2)^2+1=2x^2+6y^2$$ can be rewritten as $$\big(x^2+(y-1)^2-2\big)\big(x^2+(y+1)^2-2\big)=0,$$ which describes the union of the circles with centres $\mathrm{i}$ and $-\mathrm{i}$, each passing through $1$ and $-1$ (so with radius $\sqrt{2}$) in the Argand diagram .